# Accessing View Objects In Container View

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a `UIViewController` (1).

Within this `UIViewController` I have a `Container View` (2).

In the `Container View`'s (2) `UIViewController` (3) I have a `UILabel`.

How do I access the label text property from The first `UIViewController`(1)?

My `UIStoryboard` looks like this:

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 1):

What you likely want to do is create a reference to the child view controller in the parent view controller, and access the label property through the child view controller.

Generally, however, you don't want to have a parent object directly control a child object's elements. In essence, you want the responsibility of managing the UILabel, and its contents, to fall on whichever view controller owns it. So I would recommend designing the app logic in such a way that the child view controller totally manages its own objects.

For example, instead of simply giving public access to the UILabel on your child view controller, you could create a method like `- (void)UpdateYourLabelWithText:(NSString *)text;` that would then make updates internally. This separates your view control logic and delegates responsibility to the correct view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Implement prepareForSegue. It will be called when view controller (1) is instantiated. You can assign the segue.destinationViewController (which is view controller (3)) to a property at that time, and then you can access any of its properties.